Retag Apple-specific [accelerate] questions to [accelerate-framework]
I posted a question about Apple’s Accelerate framework and had tagged it originally as accelerate. I now realized that there is another tag, accelerate-framework, whose description makes it clearly that this is explicitly intended for Apple’s framework, so I have retagged my question accordingly.
But I have questions given the confusion between these two tags (for Apple developers, at least). Looking at the various questions posted under these tags, I see Apple Accelerate questions posted somewhat randomly between the two tags. A few thoughts:

Should swift accelerate questions be retagged as swift accelerate-framework? Likewise, should objective-c accelerate be retagged as objective-c accelerate-framework? (Can we even do this sort of conditional retagging, or must it be done manually, question by question?)

FWIW, looking at non-Swift questions with accelerate tag, Hugging Face seems to be another common use of this tag. Maybe retag huggingface (and associated tags) bearing accelerate to use accelerate-huggingface instead (where the latter would be a new tag)? It strikes me that there might be enough of those questions to warrant its own unambiguous tag. There are a number of Python questions, too.

I just updated the accelerate description with advice to use accelerate-framework for questions regarding Apple’s Accelerate framework. Is that appropriate? If not, how do we encourage the use of the latter tag for those Apple developers?


Thoughts?

What exactly is [accelerate] for? The tag wiki just says "Make large-scale mathematical computations and image calculations, optimized for high performance", which sounds like the tag is about accelerating stuff in general, which would make the tag a burnination candidate

"Is that appropriate? If not, how do we encourage the use of the latter tag for those Apple developers?" - updating the tag wiki is fine, but the problem is that most people don't read tag wikis (largely because Stack's onboarding system is garbage, and because tag wikis are kinda hidden). I suspect it might be better to get rid of the entire tag

The tag seems to be mostly about huggingface accelerate (distributed computing library), with some Apple accelerate framework. If we remove both only a handful of questions remain
